# Is there a way to have the article edit box stretch the full width of the screen in Joomla 2.5?

Tags: templates, articles, administrator, css, editor

When editing articles with EDITOR set to NONE, **is there a way to have the article edit box stretch the full width of the screen (in Joomla2.5)?**

I know you can resize the width manually, but I'd like it to be permanent. Also I find the publishing options positioned to the right of the article edit box to be a nuisance.

CURRENT LAYOUT
[image]

DESIRED LAYOUT
[image]

**My Research**

- I've done a search for administrative templates, but haven't found
  any that do what I need.
- I'm not looking for a different editor, but suggestions are still
  welcome.
- I've taken a very rudimentary look at the CSS, but haven't coded a
  solution yet. When I have more time I will work on this option and
  post the results.

Comment: Maybe you could use `JApplication` to detect the article layout and then use `addStyleDeclaration()` to override the current width (60%) for the class `width-60`. And then set the textarea to 100% width. Detecting the article layout will ensure that this change isn't applied to things like Module layouts

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just add a view override in the template:

**Understanding Output Overrides**
http://docs.joomla.org/Understanding_Output_Overrides

**Component Output Types and Layout Overrides**
http://docs.joomla.org/Understanding_Output_Overrides#Component_Output_Types_and_Layout_Overrides

The override only has to include your new CSS style modification, and the original view. For example:

File: administrator/templates/bluestork/html/com_content/article/edit.php

```
<?php

// Protect from unauthorized access
defined('_JEXEC') or die();

JFactory::getDocument()->addStyleDeclaration(".width-40 {display:none}");
JFactory::getDocument()->addStyleDeclaration("div.width-60 {width: 100%;}");

include_once JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR . '/components/com_content/views/article/tmpl/edit.php';
```

PD: I think it's much better to keep both panels shown, but one on top of the other *"div.width-40, div.width-60 {width: 100%;}"*

Comment: Thanks :) I had planned on keeping both panels, but in different positions. This looks good though, I'll try and play around with it a bit tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to what I wrote in my question, I've been using a html editor by Sven Bluege
http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/edition/editors/22284 (It's essentially the same as using Editor None, but it does syntax highlighting.)

By pressing F11 you can toggle fullscreen mode, this will stretch the editor across the entire screen. When I originally tried it, it didn't work. If it doesn't work for you, you need to click on the article edit box before pressing F11.