# How to add custom tab in component's new item editor

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-2.5, articles, k2, facebook

`I want to to insert a tab(inside some input fields and save button) in some top components' add/edit item(or article..) editor` so that while adding/editing new item/article in backend, user can add some content like facebook's open graph meta tags and save by clicking save button in the tab for that item.

Then I will End up catching those tag inputs by a plugin to insert FB meta tags when that component's those items loaded at front end.

`But don't know how this process will be implemented.` So starting with adding that tab in the above add/edit item editor is my primary concern. then i will deal with rest of the process. FYI right now i am trying to add in com_content, com_k2, com_virtuemart components.

So show me light please with details of course.

Edit: 
ok considering the toughness of adding custom tab in new/edit article page of content components, i am contemplating on pushing open graph meta tags in head of article/item page using plugin. User will include meta info in a {ogtags title=""...} tag in article or anywhere in page and by the plugin i parse it and inject og meta tags for that article page. To serve that purpose which plugin event is proper, onAfterRender() or ?

Answer (score 1):

There's no official API to extend a component. These are some alternatives:

- You can install an **Editor Button** plugin. Besides the button, the plugin can also add Javascript routines to extend the component.
- You can define a full **System Plugin**, parse the Url, and inject a whole Javascript App to the component
- With a **View Override** at template level: [Is there a way to have the article edit box stretch the full width of the screen in Joomla 2.5?](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/3612/is-there-a-way-to-have-the-article-edit-box-stretch-the-full-width-of-the-screen/3613#3613)

Comment: hm seems pretty tough with coding. I was exactly trying to do like this com's last image - http://joomlakave.com/joomla-components/open-graph-protocol-solution which saves og tag data somewhere per article.

Comment: well, that system plugin is already developed and tested to provide these features